# Не могу авторизоваться на сайте, не пойму где ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, request

Cайт:  [kingfashion.com](https://kingfashion.com) пытаюсь авторизоваться не получается.

```
s = requests.Session()
data = {'login[username]': 'yur4enko.vitya@yandex.ru', 'login[password]': 'YEvbpUZ1i5LanIFnxfVW',}
url = "https://kingfashion.com/customer/account/login/"
r = s.post(url, data=data)
s.cookies
```

Пробовал через urlib, авторизовался через браузер и смотрел какие запросы отправляются подставляю их в код и всё равно мимо.
Подскажите, может я что-то упускаю, почему код не работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Спасибо другому ответу, в котором было указано на опечатку в ссылке логина.*

Скрипт получился вот такой:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = {
    'login[username]': 'yur4enko.vitya@yandex.ru',
    'login[password]': 'YEvbpUZ1i5LanIFnxfVW',
}

session = requests.Session()

# Делаем переход к странице с авторизацией
rs = session.get('https://kingfashion.com/customer/account/')

# Получение поля form_key из формы авторизации
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'lxml')
form_key = root.select_one('#login-form > input[name=form_key]')
data['form_key'] = form_key['value']

# Авторизация
rs = session.post("https://kingfashion.com/customer/account/loginPost/", data=data)
print(rs.url)

root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'lxml')
print(root.select_one('.quick-access.shop > .account'))
```

---

Консоль:

```
https://kingfashion.com/customer/account/index/
<a class="account" href="https://kingfashion.com/customer/account/" title="Виктор Юрченко">My account</a>
```

Консоль без `form_key`:

```
https://kingfashion.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly9raW5nZmFzaGlvbi5jb20vY3VzdG9tZXIvYWNjb3VudC9pbmRleC8,/
<a class="account" href="https://kingfashion.com/customer/account/" title="">Sign in</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это сработало, только я заменил 'lxml' на ' html5lib', почему-то с lxml выводило  ошибка  будто бы нет пакета, однако он установлен.

Comment: @ВикторЮрченко, второй параметр BeautifulSoup это используемый парсер, поэтому не обязательно указывать lxml